# With ssh, how to automatically validate the first connection a an unkown server

Tags: ssh

The first time one connects an unknown server with `ssh`, he gets:

```
$ ssh root@<IP>
The authenticity of host '<IP> (<IP>)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ZmlG4578we0daN56544KJFPYwH0vOi2bMPkLTv8io.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

This is painful if the environment is fully under control and the connection is done in a script (a cloud infra creation script in my case).

Is there a way to automatically accept this server and to have the IP stored in `known_hosts` without a manual validation ?

I went through the man page, but could not find anything applicable.

Also tried `echo yes | ssh -q root@<IP>` without more success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For OpenSSH [emphasis mine]:

> `StrictHostKeyChecking`
>
> If this flag is set to `yes`, `ssh(1)` will never automatically add host keys to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, and refuses to connect to hosts whose host key has changed. This provides maximum protection against man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks, though it can be annoying when the `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts file` is poorly maintained or when connections to new hosts are frequently made. This option forces the user to manually add all new hosts.
>
> **If this flag is set to `accept-new` then `ssh` will automatically add new host keys to the user's `known_hosts` file, but will not permit connections to hosts with changed host keys.** If this flag is set to `no` or `off`, `ssh` will automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts files and allow connections to hosts with changed hostkeys to proceed, subject to some restrictions. If this flag is set to `ask` (the default), new host keys will be added to the user known host files only after the user has confirmed that is what they really want to do, and `ssh` will refuse to connect to hosts whose host key has changed. The host keys of known hosts will be verified automatically in all cases.

<sup>([source](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#StrictHostKeyChecking))</sup>

You want `StrictHostKeyChecking accept-new` (or `StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new`, both syntaxes are fine) in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or in your `~/.ssh/config`, or as an option argument to `-o` while invoking `ssh`:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new …
```

Instead of `accept-new` you may specify `no` if you think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command like this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@<IP>
```

to avoid this message, But this leaves you open to man in the middle attacks, so IMHO is is not a good idea